# How to fix "ImportError: No module named builtins" when using RQGIS to link to QGIS?

Tags: python, r, qgis

I was trying to the `RQGIS` package to use QGIS functions in `R`. However, after setting the paths using `set_env(dev = FALSE)` without problem, I got an error from `open_app()`:

```
Error in py_run_string_impl(code, local, convert) : 
  ImportError: No module named builtins

Detailed traceback: 
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.6\apps\qgis\python\qgis\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from builtins import zip
```

I have `Python` version 3.7.3 and `R` version 3.6.0 installed on my PC. Taking advice from another post, I've also installed the `future` `Python` package. It seems that the command `from builtins import zip` works just fine in a `Python` console, but the same problem persists in `R` environment. How do I fix this?